# Extending a morphism to a finite algebraic field extension

Tags: field-theory, abstract-algebra

[image: Theorem 5.21]

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 5.21 in *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, and am stuck on the portion underlined in red (note that $$\Sigma := \{(A,f) \mid A \text{ is a subring of $K$ and $f$ is a homomorphism of $A$ into $\Omega$} \}$$ is a partially ordered set: $(A,f) \leq (A', f') \iff A \subset A' \text{ and } f'\mid A=f$).

Comment: If youy ask about the result. See the proposition$1.1$ in this [document](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~vaquie/textes/uniformization.pdf).

Comment: I understand the result, but in this specific proof, I am not understanding why the underlined statement holds.

Comment: This statement is a theorem  to extending a morphism of fields .

Comment: So how would one define $\bar{g}$'(x+m'), for x+m' ∈ k' ?